# Chart Library for iPad Html5 mobile app

Tags: html, cordova, charts, kendo-ui

I am developing an ipad app using phonegap(2.1.0) and kendo ui mobile that needs to display various type of charts. as ex.(Column,bar , pie, drilldown chart.)

Currently i am using **(HighCharts)**[HighCharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com/) and Its working perfectly. But I need charts like chart in SAP BI app or SAP Sales app. They are more attractive than Highcharts. I checked **Fusioncharts**.But fusioncharts is expensive.

ANd  I also cheked SenchTouch,gRaphael. But they don't satisfy my requirement

Anyone know the chart library for my requirement .

Answer (score 1):

Try
Dojo charts - http://dojotoolkit.org/download/ Or
Extjs charts - http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs

Comment: i checked these charts already. thanx

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using Kendo UI Mobile, have you considered [Kendo UI DataViz](http://www.kendoui.com/DataViz)?

Comment: thanx for answer. but I checked Kendo UI DataViz. ANd  its not statcified my requiremnts

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what features were missing?